# move files from on server to another

Tags: hosting, move

I have to move about 600mb file from one server to another.

One way is to use filzilla, downlaod all file and then upload them to new server.
I am current doing this.

I would like to ask is there any way to copy files from one server to another directly?

I have cpanel linux hosting for both servers.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you have access to CLI you can do something like:

```
scp -r user@server1:/var/www/html/ user@server2:/var/www/html/
```

of course you will need to specify the correct paths and users.